# Adding item into a linked list, pass by reference or value?

Tags: c++

Part of my homework assignment is to implement a generic linked list.
So far I wrote this function:

---

```
template<class T>
void List<T>::insert(const T& data)
{
    List<T>::Node* newNode = new List<T>::Node(data);
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    size++;
}
```

---

As you can see I'm getting the data by reference but I could get it by value as well.
My question is what approach is better and why?

Comment: What does the List<T>::Node constructor do with data? Store a copy? Who manages the lifetime of the objects in the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++98/03, what you have is generally the correct solution.  In C++11, you can keep it the same, and you will be no worse off.  But if you want to improve efficiency, you can make some modifications.  There are two schools of thought.  The most efficient solution requires a little code duplication.  You need two functions.

```
template<class T>
void List<T>::insert(const T& data)                    // take a const reference
{
    List<T>::Node* newNode = new List<T>::Node(data);  // copy it in
...

template<class T>
void List<T>::insert(T&& data)                         // take an r-value reference
{
    List<T>::Node* newNode
        = new List<T>::Node(std::move(data));          // move it in
...
```

The other method is only slightly less efficient in most cases, and it avoids code duplication:

```
template<class T>
void List<T>::insert(T data)                           // take a value (copy)
{
    List<T>::Node* newNode
        = new List<T>::Node(std::move(data));          // move it in
...
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the "move it in" part, what problem it comes to solve?
When I'm adding data to a linked list, I'm adding a copy, right? Why I need to move things?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, you are right, one can use move semantics. I recommended const reference because I'm a C++98 dinosaur, still using classical C++ syntax. It's been 2 years since the new standard, so I've got to auto-mate my thinking.

Comment: @Doppelganger: If the original object that you supply for adding is *discardable*, i.e. you no longer need it after the addition, then you can make your code much more efficient by *relocating* (*moving* ) data from the original object to the entry in the list instead of *duplicating* (*copying*) it. That's the point of move semantics in this case.

Comment: @AndreyT You sorted the last piece of puzzle for me, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid unnecessary copy of data if passing by value, pass it by const reference as you did.

Comment: So why C++ doesn't pass by reference by default?

Comment: First, for backward compatibility with C. Second, because for basic types such as integers and floats it's more efficient to pass the value. Java doesn't claim compatibility with C and tends to pass objects by reference, but even Java passes basic types by value. C++ tends to give more control to the programmer, therefore it doesn't quietly replace value semantics with const reference semantics unless the programmer asks for it.

Comment: I agree with Michael, that it should be avoided, but be careful not to always lean on passing by reference as noted in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

By reference is better.
The data is not copied over.  Which can be significant we are talking about
class, structures, unions, etc.

By using "const" avoids the stupid programming error of storing values to parameters.
i.e.

```
void dumb_print_function(Type& d){
    d=3;  // bad programming practice.
    }
x=LongCalc();

dumb_print_function(x); // output 3 not results of "LongCalc();".
```

Comment: This does not really relate to the question at hand